# cant understand ros api properly

Tags: ros, roscpp, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking at ros::nodehandle::advertise api [here:](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#a6b655c04f32c4c967d49799ff9312ac6) , and ros::nodehandle::publish in [here](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#a317fe4c05919e0bf3fb5162ccb2f7c28), acc to these description of advertise member function :

```
 template<class M >
Publisher ros::NodeHandle::advertise    (   const std::string &     topic,
        uint32_t    queue_size,
        const SubscriberStatusCallback &    connect_cb,
        const SubscriberStatusCallback &    disconnect_cb = SubscriberStatusCallback(),
        const VoidConstPtr &    tracked_object = VoidConstPtr(),
        bool    latch = false 
)
```

the shortest vesrion of these function is as:
`handle.advertise<std_msgs::Empty>("my_topic", 1, (ros::SubscriberStatusCallback)connectCallback)`;

and for subscriber it is like:

```
template<class M , class T >
Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe   (   const std::string &     topic,
        uint32_t    queue_size,
        void(T::*)(const boost::shared_ptr< M const > &)    fp,
        T *     obj,
        const TransportHints &      transport_hints = TransportHints() 
    )       [inline]
```

with shortest version or simple description as:

```
ros::Subscriber sub = handle.subscribe("my_topic", 1, &Foo::callback, &foo_object);
```

I am using them in my node as:

```
   ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe ("/camera/depth/points", 1, cloud_cb);
    marker_pub = nh.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker> ("visualization_marker",1);
```

So why cant i create the subscriber as :

```
   ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe<visualization_msgs::Marker> ("/camera/depth/points", 1, cloud_cb);
```

and the publisher as:

```
  marker_pub = nh.advertise ("visualization_marker",1);
```

Before these i was not studying the ros api in detail but now since i need to comibine ros and gazebo i am also trying to understand ros api. I haven't seen ros api before these in detail. gazebo api was ok for me, now i am trying understand ros api also and i didn't understood these part.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250953/cant-understand-ros-api-properly/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2016-12-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The shortest version of advertise is actually:

```
template<class M >
Publisher ros::NodeHandle::advertise(const std::string & topic, uint32_t queue_size, bool latch = false)
```

Since this is templated on the message type (`M`), and the message type doesn't appear in the argument list, the message type cannot be inferred from the template arguments, so you must specify it.

Therefore you call: `nh.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker>("visualization_marker",1);` , and the third `latch` argument will default to false.

This simpler variant of `ros::NodeHandle::subscribe` is only templated on the message type:

```
template<class M >
Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const std::string &   topic, uint32_t queue_size, void(*)(M) fp, const TransportHints & transport_hints = TransportHints())
```

And since the message type (`M`) can be inferred from the type of `fp` (`void(*)(M)`), you don't need to specify any template arguments. (similarly, the `transport_hints` argument here also uses the default value).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-12-30**:
thanks, for explaining.